# how does this work in awk even without print?

Tags: awk

```
bash-3.00# cat > b1.txt
AAA,Apples,123
BBB,Bananas,124
CCC,Carrot,125
bash-3.00# cat > b2.txt
Store1|AAA|123|11
Store2|BBB|124|23
Store3|CCC|125|57
Store4|DDD|126|38
bash-3.00# awk -F"[,|]" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next} !a[$2]' b1.txt b2.txt
Store4|DDD|126|38
```

When `NR==FNR` returns true for first file `a[$1]` gets incremented. `next` brings back to beginning of the script.  But what is `!a[$2]` doing here?  How does it print without even a `print` command?

Comment: I'd advise not running / testing scripts as root unnecessarily.  Use a normal user account until you are sure the script is safe enough for `root`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [POSIX `awk` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_01):

> An awk program is composed of pairs of the form:
>
> ```
> pattern { action }
> ```
>
> Either the pattern or the action (including the enclosing brace characters) 
>   can be omitted.
>   ... [A] missing action shall be equivalent to:
>
> ```
> { print }
> ```

In your case, `!a[$2]` is the *pattern*, and the action is missing.

Comment: hi @jw013,can you add a bit more,, i mean i dont understand how !a[$2] is working to give the output..Thanks

Comment: @munish Then put that in your question.  What part of it don't you understand?  If you don't understand basic awk, you should go read an awk tutorial.  This site is for asking *specific* questions.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the previous answer:

`awk` handles true/false tests numerically; 0 is "false" and any other number is "true".  The exclam (`!`) reverses the test.

So `!a[$1]` is essentially equivalent to saying, "print if `a[$1]` is equal to 0".